# django storages and setting ACL per object

Tags: django, google-cloud-storage

I am using django-storages and [google-cloud-storage](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/master/storages/backends/gcloud.py) backend.

what I currently have is the following.

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.gcloud import GoogleCloudStorage
from storages.utils import clean_name
from django.conf import settings

class PublicImageUploadStorage(GoogleCloudStorage):
    bucket_name = settings.IMAGES_BUCKET_NAME or None
    file_overwrite = settings.IMAGES_OVERWRITE or True

    def make_public(self, name):
        name = self._normalize_name(clean_name(name))
        blob = self._get_blob(self._encode_name(name))
        return blob.make_public()
```

this is slow because it looks up blob object by name then return it so I can make it public.

**what is the most efficient way of setting *object ACL* to be public-read before saving the object to google storage ?**